# SQL Server 2008 R2 : remote access with Static ip

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, remote-access, static-ip-address

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 remotely and I have successfully connected my laptop with SQL Server 2008 R2 (server). Now I am using the IP address (dynamic) as server name, as I am in same network. Will it be possible to connect to a SQL Server with static IP?
If yes, then can I use the static IP with in my home network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in how you connect to your work site.

If you use a VPN, it's as if you was at your work site, and  then you can safely connect.

If you are not using a VPN, that's not so easy: the SQL Server IP will probably be a private IP (like 168.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x). If this is the case, this IP only works in your work site network, and it's not accesible from the outside work. To have acces to this IP you'd need to do two things:

- guess what your work site router WAN IP address is. I.e. you need to know the IP of your work site router as you see it from the internet (which is not the same as you see it from the work site). Besides, it's possible that this IP is not fixed, so you'd need a dynamic DNS to be able to know it at any time
- create a NAT or PAT mapping in the router so that when you try to access a given port of the internet IP of your router, it transfer the traffic to the internal SQL Server

The VPN solution is much better because, if you use hte second solution, anyone on the internet could tamper your SQL Server (right as you do it).

Comment: Thanks JotaBe, My IP is starts from 59.**.**.**, its a private IP. Now please tell me will it work for remote access

Comment: It doesn't look like a private IP. It could be a publicly accesible IP. However what makes the IP private or not is its accesiblity from the internet. And even if it was a public IP, I couldn't give you an answer because I don't know your network topology and configuration: routers? firewalls? It's impossible to know, unless you test it. But I insist on you using a VPN.

Comment: Sorry  JotaBe, I ma using a public IP ,and no using any VPN services. let me know whether its possible?

Comment: Actually i want to transfer data from my server to one of my client  through sql server 2008. my database is updating through ftp in every minutes , so back up restore is not possible. so please tell is there any solution for this isue

Comment: If it's a public URL and there is no firewal, it's possible. No if any of this premises is false. What do you mean by "update the database through ftp in every minutes"?